# filter data in jqgrid based on input from search toolbar

Tags: search, dynamic, jqgrid, toolbar

when the user types something in the search toolbar of the jqgrid is it automatically possible for the jqgrid to search the records and display them based on the user input in the jqgrid?

Comment: That is the point of the search toolbar, filter the results based on the user's input.  Are you retrieving the data from the server?

Comment: Actually My Question is...
on key press of the user in data grid search toolbar is it possible for immediate postback and refresh the grid based on user key press..?

Comment: Yes, you would just trigger the search event based on the keypress event of the search field.  Is that the answer to your question?

Comment: I added my comment as an answer if you want to mark it as correct. Thanks

Comment: Do you mind marking my answer as correct if it was the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You would just trigger the search event based on the keypress event of the search field

Answer (score 0):

You can set `searchOnEnter: false` on init filterToolbar.
For example:

```
$(element).filterToolbar({ searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: 'cn', ignoreCase: true });
```